# Loading pictures in a huge UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm downloading pictures for my collection view cells in the following way:

```
func loadThumbnail(..){

              ...
            //Making the request
            self.ProfilePicture.sd_setImage(with: requestUrl, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SharePreviewIcon"), completed: { [weak self] (newImage, error, cacheType, url) in

                if self == nil {
                    return
                }

                if !isActive(){ //If the cell is not active, ignore and return
                    return
                }

                return
            })

}
```

and I call loadThumbnail everytime the cell is active. Now if I have 30 cells, and 15 are active, then all 15 pictures will be loaded, and a lot of requests are being canceled or simply closed by the system because they are too many at once.

I'm still an amateur, and I just don't know what to do.
Thanks a lot.

**IMPORTANT EDIT***

Everything lives in a Tab Controller and every tab has it's own collection view. If I cancel the download in the prepareForUse() method, then only those cells who are recycled are going to be canceled.

If I switch tabs, the cells that are still active, won't get canceled, and I can't load the cells from the new collection view.

Comment: Have a look at this library https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher there is a collection view demo that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Do you think I should use kingfisher instead of SDWebImage?

Comment: Are you sure you understand isActive? Why do you check for it? + where do you call loadThumbnail?

Comment: @shannoga Hello. My problem is that I load too many pictures at once and my connections are being closed. However, I call loadThumbnail whenever the cell is active (cellForIndex). If the cell is not active and the download was unsuccessful, then I just return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that inside  `CellForItem` you get the cell reused, so a request you started on a cell can be called an other time on the same cell when scrolling.

Consider doing this -
On `CellForItem` call loadTumbnail, this will load the image as you did.

Inside the cell override - `prepareForReuse` and there you should cancel the request

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView.cancelCurrentImageLoad; // UIImageView for whatever image you need to cancel the loading for
}
```

This will cancel the request before start an other one.

An other thing - self.ProfilePicture, consider changing the imageView name to lower case.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Everything lives in a Tab Controller and every tab has it's own collection view. If I cancel the download in the prepareForUse() method, then only the cells that are recycled are going to be canceled. If I switch tabs, the cells that are still active, won't get canceled, and I can't load the cells from the new collection view.

Comment: How many tabs do you have? I don't see why loading the images after you switched to a different tab is an issue.

Comment: Well, the downloads are getting canceled (code 999) because they are too many.

Comment: I have 4 tabs*, 3 of them have collection views.